# typealiasing closure in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, type-alias

I am using an SDK developed in Objective-C. My Application is hybrid (support both Objc and Swift) and I need to use a completionBlock of SDK. In SDK side it was defined like,

```
typedef void (^SomethingCompletionBlock)(NSArray<id<Something> > *_Nullable result, NSError *_Nullable error);
```

In App side I need to use like,

```
SDKService.fetchSomething(withModel: model) { (result, error) in

    if error != nil {

       completionBlock(result, error?)

    }
}
```

I wonder what would be the signature of completionBlock in my Swift part? I am trying something like below but getting error.

```
typealias SomethingSearchCompletionBlock = (result: Array<Something>?, error: Error?)
```

Error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type
>   'SomethingSearchCompletionBlock' (aka '(result:
>   Optional>, error: Optional)')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `Void` return value and the parameter labels are not needed

```
typealias SomethingSearchCompletionBlock = (Array<Something>?, Error?) -> Void
```

Answer (score 2):

Might this will help

```
typealias SomethingCompletionBlock = (_ result: [Something]?, _ erro: Error?) -> Void
```